# Cannot connect to datastax agent

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

I am unable to connect to any nodes through opscenter. In opscenter it says that agents need to be connected inorder for opscenter to work. I checked in datastax-agent/agent.log file and found below errors.

```
ERROR [clojure-agent-send-off-pool-0] 2016-01-27 09:30:54,545 Can't connect to Cassandra (All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect))), retrying soon.
```

I checked port 9042 and 7199 both are listening..

```
x.x.x.10:9042   :::*                        LISTEN      497        499005     28550/java
```

pls advise.. what needs to be checked for this. Thanks

Comment: Try setting your listen and rpc_addresses in addres.yaml https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.1/opsc/configure/agentAddressConfiguration.html?scroll=agentAddressConfiguration__the-addressyaml-configuration-file

Comment: Also look in your opscenterd.log file for more details. I would agree with @phact on making sure both listen and rpc addresses are the same as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are few basic settings in `cassandra.yaml` to tune network connection params.

1. `listen_address : localhost`

   Address or interface to bind to and tell other Cassandra nodes to connect to. Specifying it to localhost will always do the Right Thing. Setting listen_address to 0.0.0.0 is always wrong
2. `rpc_address : 0.0.0.0`

   That unlike listen_address, you can specify 0.0.0.0, but you must also set broadcast_rpc_address to a value other than 0.0.0.0
3. `broadcast_rpc_address: localhost`

   This setting will be usefull probably for redirect conversation between nodes from broadcast_rpc_address to rpc_address (i.e. Machine has two network interfaces)

If all settings is correct for you environment try to connect with console client `cqlsh` and try to use `nodetool` for monitoring state of your nodes. After try to run OPC center

Answer (score 1):

Leave broadcast_rpc_address to rpc_address as it is to point to their respective ip address as below: and changing to 0.0.0.0 is not required.

```
10.154.3.10 - Cassandra.yaml
broadcast_rpc_address: 10.154.3.10
rpc_address: 10.154.3.10


10.154.3.10 - address.yaml
stomp_interface: 10.154.3.XX --> (Mention the IP of opscenter server)
hosts: ["10.154.3.10"]
```

Restart the datastax-agent, and in agent.log, no errors will be seen.